# How to set theme for TextView on Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, textview, themes

I'm adding TextView to Dialog with this code:

```
TextView alertView=new TextView(this);
alertView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
alertView.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
alertView.setText(Html.fromHtml(alertText));

Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(alertView);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.show();
```

In Android 4.0 it looks ok. But in Android 2.1 background of Dialog is black, and text of TextView is black too. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an overall style for your `Dialog`, define a style in your resources.

For example:

```
<style name="MyDialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/alert_light_frame</item>
</style>
```

and then set it to your dialog as below:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
```

Comment: Working fine on both versions of OS. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your TextView is using the theme from your activity instead of the dialog's theme.

You should pass the dialog's context in to the TextView's constructor:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView alertView=new TextView(dialog.getContext());
alertView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
alertView.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
alertView.setText(Html.fromHtml(alertText));

dialog.setContentView(alertView);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to create a custom dialog. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. Here's and example of custom dialog. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the color to white of textview then it will be ok for every version and if black color is your need, then change the textview background color to white

```
1.alertView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
2.alertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.white);
```